# How to configure Mantis so that an administrator is notified of all issues in the system

Tags: notifications, bug-tracking, mantis

I want to setup Mantis in a way that it sends all notifications email to the administrator, even if the administrator is not assigned or monitoring a particular project.

The administrator should get all the emails for all the activity occurring in the system. I tried to configure the Mantis' Email Notifications screen, but I fail to understand how it works.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Penuel

Answer (score 3):

Using version 1.2.6 of Mantis:

1. login as an administrator
2. Manage > Manage Configuration > Email Notifications
3. Check every box under administrator column.

Remember, if `$g_email_receive_own = OFF;` in config_inc.php, you won't get any emails notifying you of actions you are taking.